# Problems with scrolling div size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a scrollable html-div, but the size is messed up once i add another div above it within the same container.
See the code below; with the header div hidden, the other div is the correct size. Once i enable the header, the other div will extend below the bottom of its parent.

Why does it do this, and how can i prevent it?

css

```
.div2 {
    width:40%;
    height:400px;
    border:2px #000 solid;
}
.div-header {
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#fee;
    /* display:none; */
}
.div2-body {
    background-color:#efe;
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

html

```
<div class='div2'>
    <div class='div-header'>header<br>section</div>
    <div class='div2-body'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer amet Vivamus nibh sagittis Sed. Penatibus ligula interdum tincidunt orci ante tellus justo amet enim Maecenas. Phasellus amet lacus tristique habitant non dictum vitae dignissim urna urna. Tempor lobortis Curabitur dui nibh dui mi id Vestibulum fringilla sit. Quis volutpat orci laoreet vitae nec orci quis In rutrum elit. Odio Duis amet Morbi faucibus.
        Massa Nulla Curabitur convallis sapien nibh habitant hendrerit tempus eget est. Auctor enim quis et Praesent Donec convallis turpis Nam Curabitur Sed. Ac vitae risus Ut Curabitur vel id elit leo sem facilisi. Ligula consectetuer convallis sem Integer feugiat sapien risus adipiscing facilisis commodo. Enim laoreet ipsum sagittis parturient id nibh Integer porttitor wisi Donec. Ut est dui Ut sem consectetuer.
        Laoreet penatibus tortor quis gravida tortor Nullam justo Maecenas pretium a. Convallis ut morbi Integer et est Nam lacus enim Vivamus semper. Auctor Sed pede justo nisl Pellentesque lacinia Curabitur est velit sagittis. Neque venenatis et ut odio malesuada Nulla vestibulum dui iaculis consectetuer. Vivamus nascetur tempus Vestibulum tincidunt nibh Nunc.
        Risus Nulla semper tellus consequat orci ac Sed auctor leo Nulla. Vitae nec libero felis interdum dolor consequat pellentesque nunc Nam velit. Curabitur ante id egestas tellus fames Curabitur interdum quam pellentesque eget. Odio gravida ut sapien Nullam Suspendisse hendrerit lacinia Cum Curabitur metus. Congue tincidunt elit turpis eget volutpat aliquet neque est Curabitur dui. Enim Aenean Donec leo nibh vitae.
        Sed In Aenean odio molestie ut Aliquam Nulla eu convallis elit. Nam tempus ornare at eros et elit dui congue Aenean est. Ridiculus mollis dui lacinia justo dui vitae Nullam eget metus sed. Orci senectus tempor aliquam Aenean lobortis interdum ligula mi Maecenas iaculis. A et pulvinar condimentum Lorem tempus dictumst quis enim lorem amet. Laoreet non auctor Aliquam hac.
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**[edit]**

To explain further, what i am trying to accomplish:
I want a div at a fixed position in the browser, eg. `position:fixed; left:100px; top:100px` 
The div will include 2 child-divs: 1 header (non-scrollable), and a "contents" div, that should scroll once the contents would extend beyond the page bottom.

I've got most of it working, but i ran into this problem with the scrolling div.
In fact, "div2" needs to be pegged to the bottom (with a 20px margin), so it will resize itself when the browser is resized, so it *cannot* have a fixed height. I just messed around a bit with divs to get it to work, which apparently, until now, i can't :(

Hope this explains better what i try to make.

Comment: It is because you have set the height of .div2-body to be 100% so it will be as tall as it's parent (400px) and it is going out of the box :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height from 400px to 100%, its overlapping because of the fixed height in pixels.

```
.div2 {
width: 40%;
height: 100%;
border: 2px #000 solid;
```

Update: Try this

```
.div2 {
    width:40%;
    border:2px #000 solid;
}
.div-header {
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#fee;
    height:400px;
    /*display:none;*/ 
}
.div2-body {
    background-color:#efe;
    overflow:auto;
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: The original idea was 100%, but that doesn't solve the problem: the inner div will still extend beyond the parent (and go even below browser bottom edge)

Comment: div2-body + div-header should stay the same height, wether i show the header or not. The 400 pixels is an arbitrary height

Comment: I think you may have to give a fixed height to the div2-body: 400px instead of 100% for it to retain that height whether you remove the header or not, you can also give the header a fixed height too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height property from the main div(to avoid fixed height), it will automatically handle the height as per the child divs and also the scroll will work fine.

Use following css:

```
 <style type="text/css">
        .div2 {
            width: 40%;
            border: 2px #000 solid;
        }

        .div-header {
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #fee;
            /* display:none; */
        }

        .div2-body {
            background-color: #efe;
            overflow: auto;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: *seems* to work, but once i enable the header, the whole outer div2 becomes larger - not what i want!

Comment: Hello Eddy, for me it's working fine after the header enable also, can you please paste the code that you are using for enabling the header.

Comment: Surama, i'm using FireFox inspector to change the display attrubute. But the showing/hiding of the header isn't important, as in production it will always show, but its height is uncertain and can vary because its contents are inline, and will make the header-div taller if/when they overflow at the right edge.
I only tried hiding the header to confirm that it's the header that causes the div2-body to move down without resizing. And yes, i know it's because of the 100% height setting of div2: if someone can tell me how to do it with a "bottom:0" css attribute, i'll be very happy!

Answer (score 0):

**To stop the inner divs from extending beyond the parent div** you need to set an `overflow` on DIV2. Therefore:

```
.div2 {
width: 40%;
height: 400px;
border: 2px #000 solid;
overflow: hidden;
}
```